# Which password manager generates xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx?

Tags: password-manager

Looking at a password dump, I see a bunch with a particular syntax pattern. I'm guessing that a password manager software generated these ones.

The regular expression seems to be `[a-z]{6}-[a-z]{6}-[a-z]{6}`, but with exactly one lowercase letter replaced with an uppercase letter and one lowercase letter replaced with a number. Here are some fake examples I generated:

```
miemv5-gfqerg-qxlElm
etd3ez-didDhd-jqyloh
Avutev-bvjicn-4eakcd
ryevyy-oWv3gx-pwgbhy
iw1ocl-Ouortn-woymno
```

Does anyone know the name of a popular password manager program that generates passwords like these by default?

Answer (score 3):

KeePass will allow you to do this, with its Password Generation Options set to

> Generate using pattern

[image]